# Repeat Single POST on a Array of Item Numbers

Tags: python, api, post

I Believe I'm over thinking this though running into a block. I have a POST Input that is meant for a single item / `<ItemID>` use

What I need to do is repeat this call on an list of ItemID's

something like `ItemIds = ["222183515503", "222183515523","222183515533"]`

In place `<ItemID>=ItemIds</ItemID>`

Below is what I currently have.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"

payload = """
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n
<GetItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">\n
    <RequesterCredentials>\n 
        <eBayAuthToken>TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>\n 
    </RequesterCredentials>\n
    <IncludeItemSpecifics>TRUE</IncludeItemSpecifics>\n
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>\n
    <ItemID>222183515503</ItemID>\n
</GetItemRequest>"
"""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/xml",
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': "1085",
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': "0",
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': "GetItem"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string interpolation to pass in the current item id and process the request in a loop.  The below includes an example using an f string (Python 3.6+) and a .format method.

**Python 3.6+**

```
import requests

item_ids = ["222183515503", "222183515523","222183515533"]

url = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"

def payload(item):
    payload = f"""
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n
    <GetItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">\n
        <RequesterCredentials>\n 
            <eBayAuthToken>TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>\n 
        </RequesterCredentials>\n
        <IncludeItemSpecifics>TRUE</IncludeItemSpecifics>\n
        <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>\n
        <ItemID>{item}</ItemID>\n
    </GetItemRequest>"
    """
    return payload

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/xml",
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': "1085",
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': "0",
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': "GetItem"
    }

for item in item_ids:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload(item), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

**Python 2 & 3**

```
import requests

item_ids = ["222183515503", "222183515523","222183515533"]

url = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"

def payload(item):
    payload = """
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n
    <GetItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">\n
        <RequesterCredentials>\n 
            <eBayAuthToken>TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>\n 
        </RequesterCredentials>\n
        <IncludeItemSpecifics>TRUE</IncludeItemSpecifics>\n
        <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>\n
        <ItemID>{item}</ItemID>\n
    </GetItemRequest>"
    """.format(item=item)
    return payload

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/xml",
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL': "1085",
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID': "0",
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME': "GetItem"
    }

for item in item_ids:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload(item), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Both worked thank you very much! I haven't used the 3.6+ much yet is the `f` after `payload =` the write up for `format`?